# How to burn DVD in Ubuntu with Auto run

Tags: 16.04

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS. I want to burn DVD and it has to work in windows with Auto run. I tried Brasero but the DVD not showing the free space remaining in DVD. Actually I burnt 2.0 GB of content in to 4.0 GB of DVD but after burning it showing as 0 bytes free. and used space is 2.0 GB.

Comment: Is the DVD rewritable (RW)? If not then you can only write it once.

Comment: Yes, DVD is rewritable

Answer (score 2):

You'll see a second `Burn` button after you click burn the first time.  The second `Burn` button has an options screen which include the option:

```
[ ] Leave the disc open to add other files later
```

This is a check box option that is not marked by default.  You would have to checkmark that option to be able to append to the disk later.

**Some possible reasons for the default to be a closed session**

- There was a time when unclosed disc were not fully compatible with all computers.
- Some people might not want to have the content changed when presenting a disc for distribution.

**Auto run on DVD:**

To activate an auto run activity when DVD is plugged in place a file named `Autorun.inf` on the disk.  Place the name of your script or application to run (ie. `runnow.exe`) in the files content.  YOu can also include an Icon for your disk using the `icon` option.

Autorun.inf:

```
[autorun]
OPEN=runnow.exe
ICON=picture.png
```

Comment: But I need Auto run

Comment: Please an `autorun.inf` file to your disc.  I appended the explanation to the answer.

Comment: I included Autorun.inf in to disc but auto run is not working.

Comment: Can you show the content of your `autorun.inf` file?

Comment: [autorun]
open=open.bat
icon=moodle.ico                                                                                                                          Presently I am burning DVD in Windows using Cyber link power2Go burning gadget. DVD is working fine and no problem with auto run. I am trying to do same work in Ubuntu but it's not working properly. It directly showing the content in the DVD. Is there any other software is to burn DVD/ CD in Ubuntu????

Comment: I burnt a DVD in Ubuntu 16.04 using K3B-KDE burning tool. DVD is working fine in Ubuntu with Autorun. But the same DVD is not working with autorun in Windows 8. How it works on Windows??

Comment: Can you edit your message and append the formatted lines of your `autorun.inf`?  I'll test it on both OSes and see what type of discrepancy I get.

Comment: **[autorun]
open=open.bat
icon=bg.ico**